# Why does my CAST to a float give an "invalid number" error in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following example:

```
create table test_1(c1 float);
insert into test_1 values(cast('000000000000001425.6' as float));
```

When I want to insert the value, I have

> ORA-01722: invalid number

How can I pass over this error, please?

Comment: It works when I try it:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=35022669bfdfc9d47e90f7b46dfce810.  This suggests that your actual code might have some unexpected character in it.

Comment: Either that, or your numeric characters are comma as decimal separator and dot as thousands separator. That shouldn't matter, if you were inserting the right way. Why is your number (which you want to convert to float) given in single-quotes? It's supposed to be a number, not a string. Lose the quotes and you won't need to change anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely reason is that your session's `nls_numeric_characters` is set to `,.` meaning that comma is the decimal separator and dot is the thousands separator.

One easy way around that, if you really must accept `varchar2` as input, is to apply `translate` first, to convert all dots to commas and vice versa.

In the illustration below, first I use an `alter session` statement to make my session behave like yours. Then I show what you are doing now, and at the end I show how you can fix it - notice the `translate` function:

```
alter session set nls_numeric_characters = ',.';

Session altered.


create table test_1(c1 float);

Table TEST_1 created.


insert into test_1 values(cast('000000000000001425.6' as float));

Error starting at line : 10 in command -
insert into test_1 values(cast('000000000000001425.6' as float))
Error report -
ORA-01722: invalid number



insert into test_1 values(cast(translate('000000000000001425.6', ',.', '.,')
                           as float));
                           
1 row inserted.
```